# How do I decrypt an encrypted message with an RSA private key?

Tags: rsa, keys, passwords

I have an encrypted password I must decrypt as part of a challenge. Along with the password came a few **UNENCRYPTED** RSA private keys

From what I understand, all I need in order to decrypt the password is the private key, which I have. However I don't understand what software I need to use in order to decrypt the password using the private key. Does anyone know of an easy way to just plug in the encrypted password and unencrypted RSA private key to get a decrypted password or do I have to put in more effort?

Comment: [CyberChef](https://cyberchef.org/)?

Comment: How do I use this website? I found RSA decrypt but it asks for a key password. I don't have one. The output also tells me that the encrypted message length is invalid.

Comment: You shouldn't need a key password if the key isn't encrypted. Try using a file as input instead.

Comment: Where in this website do I upload a file?

Comment: The icon to the left of the bin in the top right corner.

Comment: Opening the .pem private key file as an input doesn't help.

Comment: I meant putting the encrypted password in a file as binary, but I should've been more specific.

Comment: Will it be enough to put the key in a text file then change the file extension to .bin?